# How do I know how much memory to realloc?

Tags: c, memory, alloc

I have one question regarding design of my application.
Here's the pseudo code:

```
char* buffer_to_be_filled = (char*) malloc(somesize);
fill_the_buffer(buffer_to_be_filled);
free(buffer_to_be_filled);
```

The problem is that I don't know how much size `fill_the_buffer` requires.

I was thinking about the solution inside the `fill_the_buffer` function.
I could maybe realloc the space inside when needed; the problem is, is there any way to find out how much space I have available?

How is this usually solved? I think that the one who allocates the buffer should also realloc the buffer as well, right?

NOTE : I'm filling the buffer using `fread` function, so I don't know how much space will I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function can't `realloc` the pointer that was passed to it, because `realloc` isn't guaranteed to return the same pointer it was passed (the new buffer might be too big to expand in-place). The typical solution is for the function to take a second argument specifying the size of the buffer, and to return an error code if the buffer is too small. Ideally, the error code will tell the user how big the buffer needs to be, so they can reallocate it themselves and recall the function. For example, from the man page for `snprintf` (which has this problem):

> The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() do not write more than size bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')).  If the output was truncated due to this limit then the return value is the number of characters (excluding the terminating null byte) which would have been written to the final string if enough space had been available.  Thus, a return value of size or more means that the output was truncated.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass the buffer size into the `fill_the_buffer` function. If the buffer is not big enough, your function must return an error value (f/e -1). In case of success, your function can return the count of writen bytes. This method is common practice for the C language.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `fill_the_buffer()` function is in a much better position to know... 
  - how to dimension the buffer initially and/or
  - when to re-alloc the buffer and by how much.

Therefore it may be appropriate to change the API:

`char * fill_the_buffer()`
or maybe
   `char * fill_the_buffer(size_t max_amount_caller_wants)`

The caller to fill_the_buffer() would still be responsible for disposing of the buffer returned by the function, but the allocation and dimensionning would be left to the function's logic.

This approach generally follow the idea of leaving implementation details to the lower level, making the upper levels more readable.

Comment: ok, so it's still a good "design" if a function allocates something, I retrieve it and I'm responsible for deallocation, I know that it would work, I just want to make sure it's a common practise

Comment: @javo You can do it that way, but it's really not common practice. Normally the function that allocated memory is the one that frees it. Either you pass a buffer into a function for it to be populated, or the function keeps a static buffer internally that gets overwritten the next time you call it

Comment: Yes.  I understand your concern of trying to keep the allocation and free-ing in the same method.  However this approach is not uncommon; when using this pattern, it is recommended to name the function in a way that make it more explicit that it will allocate a new buffer, for example `Get_Data_From_XYZ()` or something like that, and also to comment the API explicity, about the need for the caller to free the buffer when it isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've a suggestion if you have no problem in allocating free memory:
Allocate an initial size at the beginning of the program using `malloc`, (try to make a good guess for this initial allocation),then in the `fill_the_buffer` you may need to allocate more memory or may you don't need all allocated memory. In first case, you can allocate a suitable amount of memory (depends on to your application & your available ram) in some steps (e.g 10MB at each leakage) & then resume filling the buffer till you need more memory & repeat this while buffer fills.
In second case you can simply `realloc` to decrease size of allocated memory of your buffer.
But take care about using `realloc` specially when you want to increase size of buffer, because it usually causes big overhead (It has to find's a big enough part of free memory, then copy all of old data into new part & free the old section).